# Is the product of two sub-Gaussian random variables a sub-Gaussian random variable?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

If not, is there any way to make it hold?
Note: the random variable $x$ is called $σ^2$-sub-Gaussian if $E[e^{tx}]≤e^{t^2σ^2/2}$.

Comment: You would at least need some assumption about their dependence structure.  For instance, take the trivial counterexample $X_1 \sim$ normal$(0, 1)$ and $X_2 = X_1$.  $X_1$ and $X_2$ are both sub-Gaussian but their product is $\chi^2$ which is not sub-Gaussian.